# chrome extension access inactive tabs/ manifest must request permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, cross-domain

I want to create a chrome extension that is able to open an inactive tab of yelp's page and get some contents(like title) from that page and display those contents in the pop up. But the chrome console shows the error:

> Extension manifest must request permission.

manifest.json:

```js
var tab_title = '';
var tab_id='';
function display_h1 (results){
  h1=results;
  document.querySelector("#id1").innerHTML = "<p>tab title: " + tab_title + "</p><p>dom h1: " + h1 + "</p><p>id:"+tab_id+"</p>";
}
chrome.tabs.create({url:'https://www.yelp.com/biz/bareburger-forest-hills?osq=burger', active:false});

chrome.tabs.query({active:false}, function(tabs) {
  var tab = tabs[tabs.length-1];
  tab_title = tab.title;
  tab_id=tab.id;
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: 'document.querySelectorAll("[itemprop=description]")[0].textContent'
  }, display_h1);
});
```

```css
{
  "name": "Hello World",
  "description": "Hello World Chrome App.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "bookmarks",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/",
        "*://www.yelp.com/fe",
        "https://www.yelp.com/biz/bareburger-forest-hills?osq=burger"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "hello-16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="min-width:300px;min-height:300px;">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="id1">-</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chrome API is asynchronous so you need to move `chrome.tabs.query` inside a callback of the previous chrome.tabs.create. Otherwise it'll query the active tab which may be anything e.g. chrome:// or new tab page. Actually you don't need chrome.tabs.query - simply use the `tab` parameter in the callback of chrome.tabs.create.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried your solution and it works...but the original problem of permission is still there